# Unnecessary call of ngDoCheck() hook in Angular, why this happens?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-lifecycle-hooks, angular-component-life-cycle

Why does ngDoCheck() hook gets called when I focused out from an  tag?

Here I've add one `<input>` tag in `app.component.html` with `[(ngModel)]="text"` associates to it.
I can understand ngDoCheck() hook get's called whenever I type(update) in input field because it updates the `text` field in app component.
But why it is being called when I moved/focusOut from the  field. Please help me to get this.

Here is my app.component.html code

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="" [(ngModel)]="text" />
```

Here is my app.component.ts code

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck {
  text: any = 'Hi';

  constructor() {}

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    console.log('AppComponent ngDoCheck');
  }
}
```

In the below video debugger stops on ngDoCheck() when I click outside input field.
[ngDoCheck debugger gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkKGo.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngDoCheck` is called whenever change detection occurs - and change detection occurs after every user interaction that might have changed the state of the app.

The field losing focus changes the state of the `NgModel` component. More specifically, it causes the component to get the [touched state](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#touched), and the input to [receive](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes) the `ng-touched` CSS class.